# error: this is probably not a problem with npm. This is likely additonal logging output above

Tags: javascript, npm, terminal, noscript

C:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\space-xplorer>npm install

> node-sass@4.11.0 install C:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\space-xplorer\node_modules\node-sass
>   node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/win32-x64-72_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/win32-x64-72_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

```
  export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234
```

or configure npm proxy via

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jorge\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-01-23T22_44_17_513Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should ask a question and provide some explanation, not just throw an error up and expect an answer. But I've seen this before:

Basically NPM is trying lacking a dependency for loading node-sass, and its fallback is to get the file it needs from github.

Looks like you're behind a firewall that blocks you from direct access to github, but all you actually need is that file bindings file.

You would have to have a proxy server that is allowed to access github, or download the binary file yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is coming because of compatibility issue of node version and node sass version.

You need to downgrade node version to 10 to install node sass 4.1.0. It is not compatible with version 12 of node.

[See this discussion for the same issue.](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2662)

Compatible versions are listed on the readme https://github.com/sass/node-sass#supported-nodejs-versions-vary-by-release-please-consult-the-releases-page-below-is-a-quick-guide-for-minimium-support

Answer (score 1):

***Following 2 lines of code will resolve this error***

```
npm run build
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded the node from `14.8` to `12.18.3`, but it did NOT solve the problem.

but after that, as crazy as it is may sound, I deleted the `package-lock.json` and tried to install the package again and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Main problem was the Node version for me.
First, I have updated the Node version.
After deleting package-lock.json with node_modules,
I ran "npm i" and solved the problem...